# Suppress libtiff popup messages in Visual C code

Tags: visual-c++, libtiff

I have a Visual C++ console app linked with libtiff.
When compiled in Debug mode, the app will send warning messages to the console.  However, when compiled in Release mode, the app will show the messages in a popup dialog. Is there a setting to have the Release mode writes messages to the console?

Comment: Have you tried: TIFFSetWarningHandler(NULL) ?

Comment: We do want to see the messages, just not in Popup dialogs that will stall and wait for user input.  I guess we can set the handler to a function that prints to stdout.  But there must be a flag somewhere to make the Release build behaves the same way as the Debug build.

Comment: Yes you'd better set your own handler with TIFFSetWarningHandler. I'm not aware of any flags. Maybe it is by design. You can check the libtiff source *win32.c" to see how it was implemented.

Comment: We looked at the tif_win32.cpp and found the problem (one of our developer made changes in that file!).  Is there anyway we can give you an "up vote" or "best answer"?

Comment: I just added the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set your own handler with TIFFSetWarningHandler. You can also check the libtiff source *win32.c" to see how it was implemented.